# glimpse on a mvc hosted iis site -> post data lost

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, glimpse

As soon as I configure glimpse on IIS and disable the local policy:

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
  <runtimePolicies>
    <ignoredTypes>
      <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
    </ignoredTypes>
  </runtimePolicies>
</glimpse>
```

The POST Data get lost.

My View snippet:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("MyAction","MyController"))
{
    @Html.TextBox("name")
    <input type="submit" value="commit name"/>
}
```

My Controller snippet:

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction(string name)
    {
        ViewBag.Name = name;
        return View();
    }
}
```

`name` is always null.

It's not a routing error. It works locally on IISExpress and on IIS if i remove the runtime policy.

I believe it's a configuration issue on my side but can't figure out what. Any Idea?

Comment: Do you have any unmanaged modules or IIS extensions installed on the box where IIS isn't working?

Comment: @nikmd23 not that I'm aware of. It's pretty default config. Is that a known problem with glimpse?

Comment: Your scenario should be working. Glimpse plus some unmanaged modules that expect the request to be in a certain state sometimes has issues.

See if adding this to your Glimpse config solves the problem, but note it may break any ajax calls you have.

    <runtimePolicies>
        <ignoredTypes>
            <add type="Glimpse.Core.Policy.AjaxPolicy, Glimpse.Core" />
        </ignoredTypes>
    </runtimePolicies>

Comment: I had the same issue.  It was driving my crazy.  I was just writing up a question for SO when I decided to remove Glimpse to see it made any difference.  Sure enough, as soon as I removed Glimpse from my project, the issue went away.